# Cannot access an IP through internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dvr

I have this setup one modem and a router, to the modem is attached the DVR via LAN. What I want to do is to access the DVR but I'm not even able to get to the router config page from "outside" (WAN).

I've downloaded NOIP DUC to host redirection, but when pinging it I get timeout response.

The modem uses 192.168.1.X and the router 192.168.0.X; and the computer that runs the NOIP DUC is connected wirelessly to the router.

It has never happened this to me before in other places that I've set up DVRs

Comment: So first of all do you know that you cant reach you devices from external with ips like 192.168.1.x? You need to know your public ip adress (http://whatismyipaddress.com/de/meine-ip) . So if you know you public ip adress and the port redirection is set up properly you could be able to access the dvr.

Comment: yeah dude, that's why I told you I use NOIP dot com in order to make the dynamic public address a static one.

Comment: Why do you have two LANs?! That will make port forwarding almost impossible to set up correctly.

Comment: I know almost nothing of this, but I kinda know how to "make it work". And now it is "just working" and that is enough for me haha. My modem firewall was causing troubles.

Answer (score 0):

What I find unusual is that you have your DVR connected to the modem and not the router. Therefore you have a direct connection to the Internet with your DVR and the IP address of the DVR would be issued by your ISP. Most ISPs allow the connection of multiple devices but limit the number of IP addresses they dish out. That is why most people have a router if they want to connect more than the ISP's limit.

Anyways, in this scenario your router has two IP addresses, the External IP which is assigned by your ISP and an Internal IP which is assigned by manufacture of the router and configurable by you. Your DVR would have another IP address assigned by your ISP.

IP address that start with 192.168.x.x are reserved for LANs and are not given out in the Internet world (there are others like 10.x.x.x). If you want to know what your WAN IP address is check out this site, it will let you know.

http://whatismyipaddress.com/

Now as for accessing your router from the WAN, you need to enable it. So from a computer that is connected to your router you need to change the settings and allow remote connection. You might need to establish a port.

Now as for you DVR, bring up the settings info screen and determine the IP address it has been assigned. Since you have it connected directly to the modem and you want to access it, you need to use that IP address. That IP should give you access to the DVR through the WAN.

Lookup the ip address of your computer and DVR, if they are in the same range then you'll be able to access it through your computer. 192.168.**1**.100 and 192.168.**1**.151 are in the same range. 192.168.**0**.100 and 192.168.**1**.100 are not in the same range (assuming your are using netmask 255.255.255.0)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I've found the solution to be simpler. I've changed the modem rules for WAN to LAN and WAN to Router to allow packets. And now it is working :)